# Cassandra restoring from snapshot not showing correct tokens

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have followed [this link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsSnapshotRestoreNewCluster.html) to restore cassandra snapshot.

After restarting the first node, I found the ring token are different that what I specified in cassandra.yaml as *initial_token:*

I am using Cassandra 3.7.

I am using below command to verify the tokens provided in cassandra.yaml and being used by cassandra node,

```
cat /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml | grep initial_token
nodetool -u <usr> -pw <pwd> ring | grep <ip> | awk '{print $NF ", "}' | xargs
```

Am I missing something?
Why do I get different set of tokens for above commands?

Any comment or questions are most welcome!

Thx!

MM

Comment: were you using `num_tokens: 1` ? If not, you need to specify all the tokens for the node in the yaml. The format we will need is “initial_token: token_value, token_value, token_value”.  Of course, there will be 256 “token_value”s in that string

Comment: Thanks @LHWizard for the reply!

No, I am using *num_tokens: 256*

And yes, I have specified the same in the cassandra.yml file for 256 initial_token as,

"initial_token: token_value1, token_value2, ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had faced this issue, in which, Cassandra keeps on using auto-generated tokens. Cassandra generate tokens because initial_tokens values were not mentioned in the cassandra.yaml, the very first time Cassandra is started.

Ideally, as per documentation, we can change initial_tokens values of a running Cassandra node; by updating the cassandra.yaml and restarting cassandra.

But since it does not work, I used cassandra.yaml updated with initial_tokens value right from the beginning. This makes Cassandra not to auto-generate tokens and keep on using tokens as mentioned in cassandra.yaml right from the first time it is started.